# std::collate::transform caused segmentation fault

Tags: c++, locale, collate

When I run the following source code, got "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" at line#3

```
char s[] = "helloworld";
const std::collate<char>* pc = &std::use_facet<std::collate<char> >(std::locale("en_US"));
std::string str = pc->transform(s, s + std::strlen(s));
std::cout << str.length() << "," << str << std::endl;
```

If I replace the line#2 with

```
const std::collate<char>* pc = new std::collate_byname<char>("en_US");
```

I can get the correct result.
I think this two lines' result should be same, they all get a collate from the execution environment, so why the former got a fault?
Did I do something wrong?

PS: The c++ compiler is g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the [docs of `use_facet`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/use_facet):

> The reference returned by this function is valid as long as any `std::locale` object exists that implements Facet.

You're creating a temporary `std::locale` in your code, so that temporary is destroyed at the end of the expression, and you're left with a dangling pointer. Like this, it should work:

```
char s[] = "helloworld";
std::locale en_US("en_US");
const std::collate<char>* pc = &std::use_facet<std::collate<char> >(en_US);
std::string str = pc->transform(s, s + std::strlen(s));
std::cout << str.length() << "," << str << std::endl;
```

Comment: I've thought wrongly that `std::locale("en_US")` will be a global object, but only `std::locale()` and `std::locale::classic()` are global in fact.

Comment: @songyuanyao To put it precisely: a `std::locale` object is just a dumb(ish) collection of pointers to facets, the facets themselves being reference-counted. `classic()` returns an actual C++ reference to the global C-locale instance, while the empty `std::locale` ctor returns a copy of the global locale (incrementing the ref-count on its facets). Constructing a different locale will give you a locale object whose facets are (potentially) only used by that object - ref. count 1. Lose that object and facets go down to 0 and are destroyed.